# Only getting strange symbols when copying from pdf to text

Tags: font-encodings

So the problem i am experiencing is that the encoding of the output pdf of my .tex file is somehow custom. This is the beginning of my tex file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage[superscript]{cite}
\usepackage{calc}
\newcommand{\UnderscoreCommands}{\do\IfFileExists \do\verbatiminput%
\do\verbatimtabinput \do\citeNP \do\citeA \do\citeANP \do\citeN%
\do\shortcite \do\shortciteNP \do\shortciteA \do\shortciteANP%
\do\shortciteN \do\citeyear \do\citeyearNP%
}
\usepackage[strings]{underscore}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{minted}

\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-5mm}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-5mm}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{10mm}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-5mm}
\addtolength{\textheight}{10mm}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{20pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\headheight}{15.2pt}

\newlength{\myheight}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\textit{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}}

\bibliographystyle{plain}


\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\label{sec:intro}

We will be using a subset of a publicly available RNA-Seq
study~\cite{liu14} (the dataset is deposited in the NCBI GEO database
under accession
\href{http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/query/acc.cgi?acc=GSE51403}{GSE51403}).
The dataset represents whole transcriptome sequencing of MCF7 cell line with
and without 17 beta-estradiol treatment sequenced using polyA capture and random
priming (single-end reads, 50 bp long).

cummeRbund is a convenient R-package for visualizing your RNA-Seq data. cummeRbund assumes that reads have been aligned and that the Cufflinks suite (http://Cufflinks.cbcb.umd.edu/index.html) has been used for transcript deconvolution and (if appropriate) differential expression analysis. Due to time constraints, we will not run Cufflinks during the course. More details on how to run tophat and Cufflinks can be found at the end this document. cummeRbund is a visualization package for RNA-Seq data that was designed to help you navigate through the large amount of data produced from Cufflinks transcript assembly and Cuffdiff differential expression analysis. Such analyses typically result in a large number of inter-related files that are not intuitive to navigate through. cummeRbund helps promote rapid analysis of these files by aggregating and indexing them and allows you to easily visualize and create publication-ready figures of your RNA-Seq data while maintaining appropriate relationships between connected data points.

cummeRbund starts with re-organizing output files of a Cuffdiff analysis and storing these data in a local SQLite database. cummeRbund indexes the data to speed up access to specific feature data (genes, isoforms, TSS, CDS, etc.) and preserves relationships between these features. Access to data elements is managed via the RSQLite package and data are presented in appropriately structured R classes with various convenience functions designed to streamline your workflow. This persistent database storage means that inter-connected expression values are rapidly accessible and quickly searchable in future analyses.
See more at: \url{http://compbio.mit.edu/cummeRbund/manual_2_0.html#tth_sEc2}

\end{document}
```

Good copy:

```
We will be using a subset of a publicly available RNA-Seq study
```

Bad copy:

```
❲❡ ✇✐❧❧ ❜❡ ✉s✐♥❣ ❛ s✉❜s❡t ♦❢ ❛ ♣✉❜❧✐❝❧2 ❛✈❛✐❧❛❜❧❡ ❘◆❆✲❙❡q st✉❞2
```

Caused by:
`\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

resolved by:
`%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

But actually sometimes i do need that encoding, is there somehow a work around for this? Thanks!

.log file:

```
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 9879 strings out of 495032
 147712 string characters out of 6181718
 243128 words of memory out of 5000000
 12884 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 17552 words of font info for 41 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 44i,11n,43p,1053b,564s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
 </home/sajvanderzeeuw/.texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/ecit1000.600pk>
 </home/sajvanderzeeuw/.texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/ectt1000.600pk> <
/home/sajvanderzeeuw/.texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/ecsi1200.600pk> </h
ome/sajvanderzeeuw/.texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/ecsx1200.600pk> </hom
e/sajvanderzeeuw/.texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/ecsx1440.600pk> </home/
sajvanderzeeuw/.texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/ectt1200.600pk> </home/sa
jvanderzeeuw/.texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/ecss0800.600pk> </home/sajv
anderzeeuw/.texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/ecss1200.600pk> </home/sajvan
derzeeuw/.texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/ecsx1728.600pk> </home/sajvande
rzeeuw/.texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/ecss1000.600pk> </home/sajvanderz
eeuw/.texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/ecss2074.600pk> </home/sajvanderzee
uw/.texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/jknappen/ec/ecss1440.600pk></usr/share/texlive/te
xmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi12.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-di
st/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/font
s/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy10.pfb>
Output written on handout_02.pdf (7 pages, 191077 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 580 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 38 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 65 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: Can you add some information about the TeX distribution you're using?

Comment: I am using TeXstudio: pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)

Comment: It looks like dingbats. Your file calls, in particular, `ding2.pyg`. Your log file can tell more about the problem.

Comment: Can you add to your question the contents of the `.log` file from `Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:` to the end?

Comment: How exactly are you copying? From Adobe Reader, Evince?

Comment: Might also be a good idea to remove as much as possible from the preamble. Several of those packages ought not be relevant in this issue.

Comment: Is that log file generated when you run *with* `fontenc` or *without* `fontenc`?

Comment: @Gx1sptDTDa it is the log file generated with fontenc

Comment: rerunning your job (using tl13 pdflatex), i have no problems copying.  there certainly _are_ potential problems copying utf-8 text, but that's not this story.  (tested with acrobat reader and with evince.)